# Euler characteristic of a connected closed Riemannian $2$-manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm studying a theorem whose proof involves an application of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem to a connected closed Riemannian $2$-manifold $(M,g)$, and the proof seems to suggest that the Euler characteristic $\chi(M)$ of $M$ is equal to $2$. Is this a fact that can be proved? If so, how do I prove this fact without any basic knowledge of algebraic topology? Thank you.

**Definition.** A closed manifold is a compact manifold without boundary.

**Edit.** I'm actually working on the Geroch monotonicity about the Hawking quasi-local mass. If we denote the mean curvatures of a family of connected closed Riemannian $2$-manifolds $\Sigma_t$ by $H$, then the proof to the Geroch monotonicity involves a step as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Sigma_t}H^2 d\mu_t&=4\pi\chi(\Sigma_t)+\int_{\Sigma_t}\left(-2H^{-2}|\nabla H|^2-R-\frac{1}{2}(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2-\frac{1}{2}H^2\right)d\mu_t\\
&\leq 8\pi-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Sigma_t}H^2 d\mu_t
\end{align}$$
Did I misunderstand the inequality? Was it implying that $\chi(\Sigma_t)\leq 2$ instead? I know exactly where the term $-\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Sigma_t}H^2 d\mu_t$ came from, so I hypothesized that $\chi(\Sigma_t)=2$ at first.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking if every Riemannian $2$-manifold has Euler characteristic $2$? The answer is: most certainly not. If that is not your question, you'll have to update your post.

Comment: @QuaereVerum I was wondering if every connected closed Riemannian $2$-manifold has Euler characteristic $2$.

Comment: Then the answer is no. For oriented surfaces (which is where the Gauss-Bonnet theorem applies), the genus (number of holes) and the Euler characteristic are equivalent information: $\chi(M)=2-2g$. So the only orientable surface with Euler characteristic $2$ is the sphere.

Comment: @QuaereVerum What if $M$ is a two-sided Riemannian surface?

Comment: @Wombat what do you mean by 2-sided? If you mean orientable, then the comment of Quaere Verum already adresses the case.

Comment: Thank you all. I've edited the post with some more information. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Didier $M$ is called two-sided by the author because $M$ has a global choice of a unit normal vector field.

Comment: @Wombat Then this is equivalent to being orientable and this has been addressed above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing your edit: the author does not use the fact that $\chi(M) = 2$, but rather uses the fact that $\chi(M) \leqslant 2$.
Indeed, for a connected orientable (*two sided*) surface, the Euler characteristic is $2-2g$, where $g \geqslant 0$ is the genus.
Another way to prove this inequality is to use Betti numbers: indeed, $\chi(M) = \beta_0 - \beta_1 + \beta_2$, with $\beta_0 = \beta_2 = 1$ by the connected and orientable assumptions.

By the way, you are talking about Riemannian surfaces, but the Euler characteristic is a topological invariant, independent of any metric.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb with compact orientable surfaces:
$$\chi(M)=2-2g$$
where $g$ is the "number of holes" of $M$. For example, a torus has just one "hole", so its Euler characteristic is $0$. So the answer to your question is no.

Comment: @Wombat Even though my answer has more upvotes, I think this one deserves to be accepted, both for being first and answering your first actual question. Moreover, the answer to your edit is a straightforward derivation of this one.

Comment: @Didier you are too kind, but I think that you addressed the OP's requests better than me.